# "Can't cd to /var/cache/flashplugin-installer" error when I try to install Flash

Tags: installation, apt, dpkg, flash

```
$ sudo aptitude install flashplugin-installer

   The following partially installed packages will be configured:
   flashplugin-installer 
    No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.

0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.

Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.

Setting up flashplugin-installer (11.1.102.55ubuntu0.10.10.1) ...

cd: 161: can't cd to /var/cache/flashplugin-installer

dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2

Errors were encountered while processing:

 flashplugin-installer

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/433000), that sometimes prevents installing the flash plugin. Actually there are several reports, I just picked one with a possible workaround:

1. Check if the directory exists: `ls /var/cache/flashplugin-installer`
2. If not, create as root: `sudo mkdir /var/cache/flashplugin-installer`
3. Re-run the install command.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug but, anyhow, i found more easy installing flash in another way ( but with this method only a local installation is made ) :

- download the tar.gz package from the official website
- unpack
- copy only the file named `libflashplayer.so` to `~/.mozilla/plugins` ( if the plugins folder does not exist create it )
- start firefox with your brand new plugin installed, if you want to upgrade flash you only have to copy the new .so file over the old one.